# Trying to write low-level bit library, but I get an error, or garbage when trying to cast byte struct to char type

Tags: c, struct, byte, bit, bin

I'm trying to write functions to access individual bits in a byte, word, dword, or qword with an object-oriented style in ANSI C, but I'm not getting the results I imagine I should be.
The bit type is declared like this:

```
typedef enum {F=0,T=1} bit;
```

The byte type is declared as a struct:

```
typedef struct {
    bit b0:1;
    bit b1:1;
    bit b2:1;
    bit b3:1;
    bit b4:1;
    bit b5:1;
    bit b6:1;
    bit b7:1;
} byte;
```

I then use the function makebyte to create the byte. This is defined like so:

```
byte makebyte(bit b7, bit b6, bit b5, bit b4, bit b3, bit b2, bit b1, bit b0){
    byte out;
    out.b0=b0;
    out.b1=b1;
    out.b2=b2;
    out.b3=b3;
    out.b4=b4;
    out.b5=b5;
    out.b6=b6;
    out.b7=b7;
    return out;
}
```

Then I'm trying to convert this struct to a single byte char type, like this:

```
char byteval(byte b){
    char *out=(char)&b;
    return out;
}
```

Then here I call it in my main function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    byte k;
    k=makebyte(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0);
    printf("%c\n\n", byteval(k));
}
```

Now, my problem is that I'm basically getting garbage printed to the terminal instead of the ASCII character I'm looking for, '$'

I'm trying To Make the code Clean and Readable, since I plan on releasing it in the Public Domain. Thanks in advance!

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that the order of bit fields is up to the implementation, and can't be controlled or (easily) checked. You also don't know the size of `bit`, so you can't guarantee that the byte you want will be in the first character of `byte`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove all the pointer punning and convert the function to macro. I would also use *union* for this purpose

```
typedef union 
{
    struct 
    {
        unsigned char b0:1;
        unsigned char b1:1;
        unsigned char b2:1;
        unsigned char b3:1;
        unsigned char b4:1;
        unsigned char b5:1;
        unsigned char b6:1;
        unsigned char b7:1;
    };
    unsigned char uc;
} byte;

#define makebyte(b7, b6, b5, b4, b3, b2, b1, b0) \
    (byte){b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    byte k;
    k=makebyte(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0);
    printf("%c\n\n", k.uc);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/8WEezYdWa

You need to know that standard does not define order of bits in the bitfield struct. *gcc* is consistent and does it your way.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
char byteval(byte b){
    char *out=(char)&b;
    return out;
}
```

Is invalid for two reasons, actually the same reason twice.

On the first line, you're converting an address to a `char` type, then converting it back to a pointer type.  Converting a pointer to an integer type and back is only valid if the integer type is large enough to hold the pointer value, which in this case it's not.

You should be converting to a `char *`:

```
char *out = (char *)&b;
```

On the second line, you're converting a pointer to a `char` again and returning it from the function.  You don't actually want to return the pointer, but what the pointer points to:

```
return *out;
```